# Transcript rewrite

Tags: community-college

I took a class that I thought I was auditing and got outside help.

Is there any way to fix this?

I did this at a community college.

Grades have gone out and I realized there was a mistake made.

Comment: I don't see how your four statements fit together.

Comment: @Buffy when I signed up for classes I made a mistake.

Comment: Do you mean that you accidentally registered to take the course for credit, instead of registering as an auditor? How is “got outside help” relevant?

Comment: Did "outside help" result in a charge of dishonesty?

Answer (score 3):

Most colleges and universities do have some sort of mechanism to correct errors in a transcript.  It usually requires some fairly high-up administrator to sign off.

Your case is tricky because the error was apparently yours, not the school's.  It's generally the student's responsibility to decide how to register for courses, and to verify their enrollment at the start of the term to check that it's what they want. And saying "I meant to audit that course instead of taking it for credit" is extra tricky because it's exactly what a dishonest student might say if they actually always did mean to take it for credit, but simply didn't do well in the course and now want to erase their low grade.

In order to get such a change approved, I expect you'll need to present some sort of evidence that you really thought you were auditing.  For instance, did you discuss your audit status with the course instructor, or some other neutral person, during the course?  You could try to get a statement from them.

You'll probably also need a good explanation for why you didn't catch the mistake sooner.  Did you have some sort of life disruption going on?  Were there IT problems?  Does the college enrollment system display your registration in a confusing way?  Did the course instructor or some other official mistakenly tell you that you were signed up to audit?

Answer (score 0):

Check in with your registrar office and see what they can do. You would have student portal to sign up for courses if you're enrolled in school/for the academic year. I don't think there's a way to "edit" your transcript per se, but you can always retake the course.

Comment: "per say" or "per se" ?

Comment: Yes, thank you @Solar Mike. I knew there was something wrong when I typed it. I just returned from Asia and my English, unfortunately, has deteriorated quite a bit.